# igraph in R: Missing edges when merging 2 graphs

Tags: r, merge, union, igraph, vertex

I have made 2 distinct network in igraph and want to merge them into one graph. Each edge of each individual graph needs to be present in the combined graph, but there are multiple edges that are missing. How can I get each edge to appear in the merged graph?

**A reproducible example**

```
edge_1 <- data.frame(from = c("E", "D", "D", "A", "E", "D", "D", "B", "F", "A", "F"), to = c("B", "C", "F", "E", "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "E", "D"))
vtx_1 <- data.frame(Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))

edge_2 <- data.frame(from = c("C", "E", "F", "A", "E", "A", "B", "A", "D", "B", "D"), to = c("F", "C", "C", "E", "A", "C", "C", "E", "F", "C", "C"))
vtx_2 <- data.frame(Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))

library(igraph)
g1 <- graph_from_data_frame(edge_1, vertices = vtx_1, directed = TRUE)
g2 <- graph_from_data_frame(edge_2, vertices = vtx_2, directed = TRUE)

plot(g1 %du% g2, 
     edge.arrow.size = 0.5)

plot(g1 %u% g2, 
     edge.arrow.size = 0.5)
```

**The results of these graphs are the following:**
[image: Disjointed and Union Graphs]

**The Issue**

*The Disjointed graph:*
Top graph: Vertex C has 6 incoming edges; 1 outgoing edge
Bottom graph: Vertex C has 2 incoming edges

*The Union graph*:
Vertex C has 6 incoming edges; 1 outgoing edge

The union graph needs to show 8 incoming edges (the total of all incoming edges for both graphs) and 1 outgoing graph.

To note: other vertices (not just vertex C) also display missing edges in the union graph.

**Any ideas on how all total edges can be shown in the union graph?**

Thank-you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multigraph from two simple graphs in igraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74427226/multigraph-from-two-simple-graphs-in-igraph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get what you want is to just use the edgelists again.

```
edge_merged = rbind(edge_1, edge_2)
vtx_merged = data.frame(Names = union(vtx_1$Names, vtx_2$Names))

gmerged <- graph_from_data_frame(edge_merged, vertices = vtx_merged, 
    directed = TRUE)
plot(gmerged, edge.arrow.size = 0.5)
```

[image: Merged graphs]

If you don't have edgelists, you can generate them using `as_edgelist`.